# How can I have Vagrant's provision fail if a subcommand fails?

Tags: vagrant

If one of the lines in `config.vm.provision "shell"` fails, Vagrant keeps going forward with the rest of the script. How can I make any error cause the provision process to fail?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think vagrant provides for an option on the shell provisioning but it can be managed within your script itself by using [The Set Builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin)

```
#!/bin/bash    
set -e
.... rest of your commands - first command which fails will break the script and exits ...
```

Comment: This works to end the script and inform the user... but vagrant still thinks that provisioning has succeeded.

Comment: not sure if it's possible. i made this issue https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8301

Answer (score 0):

I want exactly this.  Looks like it's not possible so I've settled for a panicky banner instead.  The child scripts contain `set -e` to exit if anything fails.

`Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "setup-files/parent.sh"`
```

`parent.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/vagrant/setup-files/child1.sh &&
/home/vagrant/setup-files/child2.sh 

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then # If: last exit code is non-zero
    echo !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    echo An error occurred running build scripts
    echo !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
fi
```